# Yaourt: how to list dependencies for a package?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, yaourt

How can I list the dependencies for a given package?

I thought this should be an easy task for Google, but I only found `yaourt -Sq --depends <pkg>`, which lists all packages that depend on `<pkg>`.

I was not able to find the other way around: list all dependencies that need to be installed for `<pkg>`.

Comment: Yaourt isn't a package manager. Either use pacman (`pacman -Qi $pkg` or `-Si` if it is not in the local db) or expac (`expac -S %D $pkg`).

Comment: @jasonwryan would either of those help if I wanted to list the dependencies of an AUR package though?

Comment: @terdon No, you would need an AUR helper for that. Something like Cower.

Comment: `yaourt -Qi $pkg` worked for me